# Проблема при получении JSON, Kotlin - Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Получаю ошибку - Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Понимаю что ошибка в том что ожидается массив а возвращается объект, но так как только учусь не могу понять что надо исправить.

Код основной:

```
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()
        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Ostatki>?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Ostatki>?>,
                response: Response<List<Ostatki>?>
            ) {
                val responseBody = response.body()!!

                val myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
                for (myData in responseBody){
                    myStringBuilder.append(myData.stock_name)
                    myStringBuilder.append("\n")

                }

                Log.d("MainActivity",myStringBuilder.toString())

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Ostatki>?>, t: Throwable) {
                print("g")
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onFailure: "+t.message)
            }
        })
```

```
Мой JSON
```

```
{
    "ostatki": [
        {
            "stock_name": "my sklad",
            "count": 50
        },
        {
            "stock_name": "my sklad2",
            "count": 150
        }
    ]
}
```

Думаю я как то не верно написал эту строку:

```
call: Call<List<Ostatki>?>
```

Мой дата класс

```
package com.rvvtux.myktor

data class Ostatki(
    val count: Int,
    val stock_name: String
)
```

Comment: Вы не показали ваши дата-классы. Если `Ostatki` - это модель элемента массива, то вам нужен ещё один класс с полем `ostatki: List<Ostatki>?` и использовать его как модель ответа, то есть везде заменить `List<Ostatki>` на новый класс, а в конце взять список из него.

Comment: поддерживаю @woesss. в ошибке говорится "ожидается массив, а приходит объект". вам надо ожидать объект, у которого есть поле "массив Остатки"

Comment: либо, вы можете удалить из json'а строки 1-2  `{ "ostatki": [` и предпоследнюю-последнюю `] }`.  тогда вы будете получать не Объект, а Массив.

Comment: package com.rvvtux.myktor

data class Ostatki(
    val count: Int,
    val stock_name: String
)

Comment: Это мой дата класс, что надо здесь изменить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю всех!
Разобрался! Передал json в виде массива и взлетело!